# Shape of Eddy Currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

I've always had this question and didn't know how to answer it - Why do eddy currents have the shape they do? Why are they circular eddies?

Answer (score 3):

$Are\ you\ sure\ they\ are\ always\ circular?\ Then\ I\ think\ you\ are\ wrong.$
[image: Eddy current]
*Example of non circular Eddy current*

---

**Definition of Eddy Current:** *They are loops of electrical current induced within conductors by a changing magnetic field in the conductor, due to Faraday's law of induction. Eddy currents flow in closed loops within conductors, in planes perpendicular to the magnetic field.*
The Eddy currents flow in loop but the shape of loop is depends on shape of the conductor.

---

**Why are they in closed loop?** *Actually they are opposing the magnetic field. The loop shape can be understood by [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law/%20*Lenz's%20Law*) and [Right Hand Thumb Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule/%20*Right%20Hand%20Rule*).*

---

For more details you can see this link [Eddy Current](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIoaORo-_LAhWECo4KHeauDiAQFghBMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEddy_current&usg=AFQjCNHcDypowf7kQYxFmrlZbgEIQd9pLw/%20*Eddy%20Current*)

Comment: Source of image: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current)

Comment: @K.CKarthik, welcome to Physics SE, if an answer satisfies you, it's a good idea to indicate that by accepting it. Check https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers